# TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. When calling a model with tf.data.dataset.map

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, object-detection-api

I am calling a model in a function detect:

```
def detect(img):
    detector_output = detector(tf.reshape(img, (1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2])))
    classes = detector_output['detection_classes'][0].numpy()
    most_likely = tf.convert_to_tensor(classes[0])
    box = detector_output['detection_boxes'][0][0]
    box = tf.math.multiply(box, [img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[0], img.shape[1]])
    box = tf.cast(box, tf.int16)
    return (box, most_likely)
```

this is called in another function reads via tf.data.datasets map api

```
dataset = dataset.map(reads, num_parallel_calls = AUTO).batch(32)
```

I think the issue is that this tensorflow hub model (or all object detection models I could find) does not support batching.

Calling the function via reads by itself works fine.

except if I use the `tf.function` decorator, then weirdly even by itself `detect(img)` throws the same error.

I tried with several models from [here](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/collections/object_detection/2) with the same result.

detector needs the shape with the 1 dimension up front.
I know there should be some reverse `flatten()` or `squeeze()` but I couldn't find it, apologies for the bad style!
The issue is also likely here in the reshaping.

the full error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (1, None, None, 3). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Edit: I fixed the error by using tf.expand_dims instead of reshaping above.
I'd still be glad for a good explanation to understand better what went trong.

Thank you for your help!